# Speak Function to say numbers from a list in a defined delay

Tags: list-manipulation, sound

I want to create a script that "speaks" a few digits.
This is what I got thus far:

`A = RandomChoice[0 ;; 9, 15];
Do[Speak[i], {i, A}]`

Mathematica "says" those 15 digits, but the time interval between each digit is arbitrary, sometimes takes even a few seconds.

What change do I need such that digits are to be spoken by an interval of, say, 1 second?

Comment: I don't know why there is a delay between each digit with your current approach, but generally, if you want to control timing you need to insert `Pause` into the `Do` loop. Another way would be to use `RunScheduledTask`.

Comment: `Pause` solves the problem. Thank you.